# Can System.Threading.Timer callback be a private method of class and use private members safely if initialized in constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a class which requires background timer to emit some metrics every minute.

```
public MyClass(...)
        {            
           // some member variables defined

            // create timer and start
            _metricEmitTimer = new Timer(ComponentTimerCallback, null, 0, 60000);            
        }
```

ComponentTimerCallback is private method of the class that logs metrics. Logic is irrelevant to the question.

```
private void ComponentTimerCallback(object state)
{
     // logic uses member variables and logs some metrics
}
```

Should I be concerned of a race condition where my callback delegate is called before the class is initialized?
I assumed not since the callback is a private method of that class. I assume it cannot exist unless the object is created?

Comment: ok thanks Andy. The timer also uses some instance variables. I'm assuming it does not matter if I initialize them before or after I instantiate new Timer() in the constructor. Currently they are before.
I understand that the timer can only start once the MyClass constructor creation returns?

Comment: wait -- disregard that. That shouldn't even compile -- `ComponentTimerCallback` must be static. If you moved that timer instantiation in to the constructor, then it would work.

Comment: it compiles unfortunately so I am a bit confused. It works currently. But I've seen a bug in the metrics logs where I suspect non-initialized variables. Hence my suspicion and the concern.

Comment: Look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/thZHzx). What compiler would allow you to compile that code?

Comment: oh i see - you are showing the constructor -- i thought you were in the class scope. So you are already doing what's in `TestMe3`. Then my original comment stands. Too bad I deleted it. You would want to make sure your timer instantiation is the last thing your constructor does after it initializes all other variables.

Comment: _"Should I be concerned of a race condition where my callback delegate is called before the class is initialized?"_ -- it depends on the implementer of the event. But yes, in theory you should. The fact that the handler is a `private` method makes absolutely no difference at all. See duplicate.